# Customising the UITabBar.appearance in each View Controller [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, tabbar

I'm trying to set the tab bar to have a different background image on each view controller.

```
class CharacterVC: UIViewController {

var tabBarApparence = UITabBar.appearance()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tabBarApparence.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "BlueTB") //Loaded from Image Asset
}
```

This works fine and changes it to blue in that view, however when I go to the next view it stays the blue colour and doesn't change to the red colour which I programmed in with this code:

```
class AnonVC: UIViewController {

var tabBarApparence = UITabBar.appearance()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tabBarApparence.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "RedTabBar")
    // addtional code here
}
```

I have an additional 2 view controllers, one should display the green version of the image and the other the purple version of the image.

Any suggestions which could fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to change appearance of TabBar in a view controller is very easy. You can this in function viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear. The code is the next:

```
// Set color of titles and icons in tabBar
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
// Set color of background tabBar
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

Comment: that worked for when i went to each view thanks! However, when i go back onto a previous view it stays the same as the last one? Any idea how i can have it so it swaps to the one which has been set for that view?

Comment: wait! i got it to work with @Igor suggestion of viewWillAppear() thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace code to `viewWillAppear()`
2. Better set backgroundImage to tabBar, not to `UITabBar.appearance()`